# An algorithm for Poincare recurrence time

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Define the function $[0,+\infty) \rightarrow R$:

$$ f = \cos (t) + \cos (\sqrt{2} t) + \cos (\sqrt{3} t) + \cos (\sqrt{5} t ) . $$

I want a number $t $ bigger than $10^7$ such that

$$ f(t) > 4 - 10^{-9} . $$

Can anyone give me such a number? Ultimately, I want an algorithm which works for arbitrary precision (say $10^{-900}$).

Comment: how do you do $$ \cos (t) + \cos (\sqrt{2} t) + \cos (\sqrt{3} t) > 3 - 10^{-9}? $$

Comment: It is an equally difficult problem. Anyway, I want a general algorithm.

Comment: It's not too hard to find values "by hand" by which I don't mean by hand, but with only some simple calculations, no lattice reduction. Find really good rational approximations to $\sqrt{2}$, so that you get $p_2-q_2\sqrt{2}$ is small. Then consider good approximations to $\sqrt{3}q_2$ with small denominators, so $p_3-q_2q_3\sqrt{3}$ is small. Then $q_2q_3\sqrt{3}$ is close to the integer $p_3$, and if you chose the right meanings of "really" and "small," $q_2q_3\sqrt{2}$ is still close to the integer $p_2q_3$. I think this is typically far from efficient.

Comment: One example: $t=32733777552734744709300 \times 17310639413 \times 122447 (2\pi), f(t) = 3.99999999946$.

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of finding sufficiently good rational approximations to $\frac{1}{2 \pi}$, $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2 \pi}$, $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2 \pi}$, $\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2 \pi}$, then taking t as their least common denominator?

Comment: More of a comment than an answer: This method, http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7379751, will also find the simultaneous approximations needed to solve your problem.

Comment: Very relevant: arXiv:1705.01444v1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to find an $s$ such that $s, \sqrt{2} s, \sqrt{3} s, \sqrt{5} s$ are all close to integer. Your $t$ is then given by $2\pi s.$ The first question is a problem in simultaneous Diophantine approximation, an algorithm for which (using lattice reduction) is given by [W.Bosma](http://math.ucsd.edu/~kedlaya/ants10/bosma/paper.pdf) (probably among others).

Answer (score 2):

If you take a random $T$ in some large interval (large enough that 
$\cos(T)$, $\cos(\sqrt{2} T)$ and $\cos(\sqrt{3} T)$ $\cos(\sqrt{5} T)$ are essentially independent), the probability that each of these is greater than
$1 - 10^{-9}/4$ is approximately $(10^{-3}/(\sqrt{2} \pi))^4 \approx 2.5 \times 10^{-15}$.  However, we can do  better.  If we take $T = 2 \pi x$ where $x$ is an integer, $\cos(T) = 1$.  If $x$ is a linear combination (with small integer coefficients) of denominators of convergents of the continued fraction for $\sqrt{2}$, we can ensure $\cos(\sqrt{2} T)$ close enough to $1$.
Then we have only two other cosines that need to be close to $1$, and the 
probability should be about $5 \times 10^{-8}$, well within the capabilities of a random search on a fast computer.

Comment: You might get to $10^{-9}$ this way, but never to $10^{-900}$.  The approach via simultaneous Diophantine approximation (using the LLL algorithm, or better yet PSLQ) is polynomial in the exponent and readily solve the question for $10^{-900}$ (as was done by **O.S.Dawg**) and beyond.